# ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am having some serious issue when running Hive query in my master node. I have 3 cluster setup(1 namenode, 2 datanodes).

Version:
Hadoop: 2.7.3
Hive: 2.1.0
Java: openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
OS: ubuntu 16.04.1
Env: Amazon EC2

I have installed Hive in masternode and started all daemons from master node using start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh. I checked all daemons in master and slave nodes, all are running fine. When I connected to Hive and ran sample query, all daemons in master node are getting down, but daemons in datanodes are still running. Please find the below log details from hadoop-hduser-datanode-namenode.log.

```
2016-11-26 10:55:45,667 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Jetty bound to port 45414
2016-11-26 10:55:45,667 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
2016-11-26 10:55:45,794 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@localhost:45414
2016-11-26 10:55:45,862 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.web.DatanodeHttpServer: Listening HTTP traffic on /0.0.0.0:50075
2016-11-26 10:55:45,913 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: dnUserName = user123
2016-11-26 10:55:45,913 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: supergroup = supergroup
2016-11-26 10:55:45,940 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue
2016-11-26 10:55:45,950 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 50020
2016-11-26 10:55:45,970 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Opened IPC server at /0.0.0.0:50020
2016-11-26 10:55:45,980 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Refresh request received for nameservices: null
2016-11-26 10:55:46,000 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Starting BPOfferServices for nameservices: <default>
2016-11-26 10:55:46,011 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to namenode/175.45.20.822:9000 starting to offer service
2016-11-26 10:55:46,022 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2016-11-26 10:55:46,022 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 50020: starting
2016-11-26 10:55:46,308 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Using 1 threads to upgrade data directories (dfs.datanode.parallel.volumes.load.threads.num=1, dataDirs=1)
2016-11-26 10:55:46,315 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Lock on /tmp/hadoop-user123/dfs/data/in_use.lock acquired by nodename 15455@namenode
2016-11-26 10:55:46,357 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Analyzing storage directories for bpid BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866
2016-11-26 10:55:46,357 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Locking is disabled for /tmp/hadoop-user123/dfs/data/current/BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866
2016-11-26 10:55:46,361 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Setting up storage: nsid=148839353;bpid=BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866;lv=-56;nsInfo=lv=-63;cid=CID-c331d6bd-518b-4b20-a20b-b3bfb3c2896f;nsid=148839353;c=0;bpid=BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866;dnuuid=c98d92d6-14ac-4722-acb4-60727105f60c
2016-11-26 10:55:46,395 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl: Added new volume: DS-135f7e8e-5984-47e7-89f2-d41e1bf2cf36
2016-11-26 10:55:46,396 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl: Added volume - /tmp/hadoop-user123/dfs/data/current, StorageType: DISK
2016-11-26 10:55:46,401 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl: Registered FSDatasetState MBean
2016-11-26 10:55:46,402 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl: Adding block pool BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866
2016-11-26 10:55:46,403 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl: Scanning block pool BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866 on volume /tmp/hadoop-user123/dfs/data/current...
2016-11-26 10:55:46,413 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl: Time taken to scan block pool BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866 on /tmp/hadoop-user123/dfs/data/current: 11ms
2016-11-26 10:55:46,414 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl: Total time to scan all replicas for block pool BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866: 12ms
2016-11-26 10:55:46,414 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl: Adding replicas to map for block pool BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866 on volume /tmp/hadoop-user123/dfs/data/current...
2016-11-26 10:55:46,429 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl: Time to add replicas to map for block pool BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866 on volume /tmp/hadoop-user123/dfs/data/current: 15ms
2016-11-26 10:55:46,429 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl: Total time to add all replicas to map: 15ms
2016-11-26 10:55:46,497 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.VolumeScanner: VolumeScanner(/tmp/hadoop-user123/dfs/data, DS-135f7e8e-5984-47e7-89f2-d41e1bf2cf36): no suitable block pools found to scan.  Waiting 1629134398 ms.
2016-11-26 10:55:46,499 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DirectoryScanner: Periodic Directory Tree Verification scan starting at 1480165886499 with interval 21600000
2016-11-26 10:55:46,501 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Block pool BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866 (Datanode Uuid null) service to namenode/175.45.20.822:9000 beginning handshake with NN
2016-11-26 10:55:46,510 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Block pool Block pool BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866 (Datanode Uuid null) service to namenode/175.45.20.822:9000 successfully registered with NN
2016-11-26 10:55:46,510 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: For namenode namenode/175.45.20.822:9000 using DELETEREPORT_INTERVAL of 300000 msec  BLOCKREPORT_INTERVAL of 21600000msec CACHEREPORT_INTERVAL of 10000msec Initial delay: 0msec; heartBeatInterval=3000
2016-11-26 10:55:46,563 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Namenode Block pool BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866 (Datanode Uuid c98d92d6-14ac-4722-acb4-60727105f60c) service to namenode/175.45.20.822:9000 trying to claim ACTIVE state with txid=6318
2016-11-26 10:55:46,564 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Acknowledging ACTIVE Namenode Block pool BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866 (Datanode Uuid c98d92d6-14ac-4722-acb4-60727105f60c) service to namenode/175.45.20.822:9000
2016-11-26 10:55:46,635 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Successfully sent block report 0xe4aa15bb18cd,  containing 1 storage report(s), of which we sent 1. The reports had 78 total blocks and used 1 RPC(s). This took 3 msec to generate and 68 msecs for RPC and NN processing. Got back one command: FinalizeCommand/5.
2016-11-26 10:55:46,636 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Got finalize command for block pool BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866
2016-11-26 10:56:46,536 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(175.45.20.822:50010, datanodeUuid=c98d92d6-14ac-4722-acb4-60727105f60c, infoPort=50075, infoSecurePort=0, ipcPort=50020, storageInfo=lv=-56;cid=CID-c331d6bd-518b-4b20-a20b-b3bfb3c2896f;nsid=148839353;c=0) Starting thread to transfer BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742505_1686 to 175.45.20.823:50010
2016-11-26 10:56:46,569 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DataTransfer: Transmitted BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742505_1686 (numBytes=5798) to /175.45.20.823:50010
2016-11-26 11:12:57,577 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742514_1695 src: /175.45.20.822:36416 dest: /175.45.20.822:50010
2016-11-26 11:12:57,669 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /175.45.20.822:36416, dest: /175.45.20.822:50010, bytes: 5780, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1542813275_1, offset: 0, srvID: c98d92d6-14ac-4722-acb4-60727105f60c, blockid: BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742514_1695, duration: 68626648
2016-11-26 11:12:57,669 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742514_1695, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2016-11-26 11:12:57,712 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742515_1696 src: /175.45.20.822:36420 dest: /175.45.20.822:50010
2016-11-26 11:12:57,795 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /175.45.20.822:36420, dest: /175.45.20.822:50010, bytes: 5175, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1542813275_1, offset: 0, srvID: c98d92d6-14ac-4722-acb4-60727105f60c, blockid: BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742515_1696, duration: 38025952
2016-11-26 11:12:57,795 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742515_1696, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2016-11-26 11:12:58,240 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742516_1697 src: /175.45.20.822:36426 dest: /175.45.20.822:50010
2016-11-26 11:12:58,564 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /175.45.20.822:36426, dest: /175.45.20.822:50010, bytes: 32414403, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1542813275_1, offset: 0, srvID: c98d92d6-14ac-4722-acb4-60727105f60c, blockid: BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742516_1697, duration: 313068763
2016-11-26 11:12:58,564 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742516_1697, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2016-11-26 11:12:58,627 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742517_1698 src: /175.45.20.822:36430 dest: /175.45.20.822:50010
2016-11-26 11:12:58,651 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /175.45.20.822:36430, dest: /175.45.20.822:50010, bytes: 498, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1542813275_1, offset: 0, srvID: c98d92d6-14ac-4722-acb4-60727105f60c, blockid: BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742517_1698, duration: 7376542
2016-11-26 11:12:58,651 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742517_1698, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2016-11-26 11:12:58,664 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742518_1699 src: /175.45.20.822:36434 dest: /175.45.20.822:50010
2016-11-26 11:12:58,677 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /175.45.20.822:36434, dest: /175.45.20.822:50010, bytes: 26, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1542813275_1, offset: 0, srvID: c98d92d6-14ac-4722-acb4-60727105f60c, blockid: BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742518_1699, duration: 10092926
2016-11-26 11:12:58,677 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742518_1699, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2016-11-26 11:12:58,723 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742519_1700 src: /175.45.20.822:36438 dest: /175.45.20.822:50010
2016-11-26 11:12:58,770 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /175.45.20.822:36438, dest: /175.45.20.822:50010, bytes: 240636, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1542813275_1, offset: 0, srvID: c98d92d6-14ac-4722-acb4-60727105f60c, blockid: BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742519_1700, duration: 40609207
2016-11-26 11:12:58,770 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742519_1700, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2016-11-26 11:13:04,927 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742520_1701 src: /175.45.20.822:36456 dest: /175.45.20.822:50010
2016-11-26 11:13:04,953 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /175.45.20.822:36456, dest: /175.45.20.822:50010, bytes: 275749, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_230151483_1, offset: 0, srvID: c98d92d6-14ac-4722-acb4-60727105f60c, blockid: BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742520_1701, duration: 21419056
2016-11-26 11:13:04,953 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742520_1701, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2016-11-26 11:13:10,781 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742521_1702 src: /175.45.20.822:36466 dest: /175.45.20.822:50010
2016-11-26 11:13:16,567 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(175.45.20.822:50010, datanodeUuid=c98d92d6-14ac-4722-acb4-60727105f60c, infoPort=50075, infoSecurePort=0, ipcPort=50020, storageInfo=lv=-56;cid=CID-c331d6bd-518b-4b20-a20b-b3bfb3c2896f;nsid=148839353;c=0) Starting thread to transfer BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742515_1696 to 175.45.20.823:50010
2016-11-26 11:13:16,568 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DataTransfer: Transmitted BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742515_1696 (numBytes=5175) to /175.45.20.823:50010
2016-11-26 11:13:18,158 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /175.45.20.822:36466, dest: /175.45.20.822:50010, bytes: 35339, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_230151483_1, offset: 0, srvID: c98d92d6-14ac-4722-acb4-60727105f60c, blockid: BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742521_1702, duration: 7374403211
2016-11-26 11:13:18,159 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742521_1702, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2016-11-26 11:13:18,172 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742523_1704 src: /175.45.20.822:36476 dest: /175.45.20.822:50010
2016-11-26 11:13:18,182 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /175.45.20.822:36476, dest: /175.45.20.822:50010, bytes: 392, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_230151483_1, offset: 0, srvID: c98d92d6-14ac-4722-acb4-60727105f60c, blockid: BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742523_1704, duration: 7185360
2016-11-26 11:13:18,182 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742523_1704, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2016-11-26 11:13:18,208 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742524_1705 src: /175.45.20.822:36482 dest: /175.45.20.822:50010
2016-11-26 11:13:18,215 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /175.45.20.822:36482, dest: /175.45.20.822:50010, bytes: 35339, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_230151483_1, offset: 0, srvID: c98d92d6-14ac-4722-acb4-60727105f60c, blockid: BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742524_1705, duration: 5068037
2016-11-26 11:13:18,215 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742524_1705, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2016-11-26 11:13:18,232 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742525_1706 src: /175.45.20.822:36486 dest: /175.45.20.822:50010
2016-11-26 11:13:18,240 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /175.45.20.822:36486, dest: /175.45.20.822:50010, bytes: 275749, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_230151483_1, offset: 0, srvID: c98d92d6-14ac-4722-acb4-60727105f60c, blockid: BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742525_1706, duration: 6277417
2016-11-26 11:13:18,241 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866:blk_1073742525_1706, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2016-11-26 11:13:22,568 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Scheduling blk_1073742514_1695 file /tmp/hadoop-user123/dfs/data/current/BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir2/blk_1073742514 for deletion
2016-11-26 11:13:22,569 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Scheduling blk_1073742515_1696 file /tmp/hadoop-user123/dfs/data/current/BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir2/blk_1073742515 for deletion
2016-11-26 11:13:22,569 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Scheduling blk_1073742516_1697 file /tmp/hadoop-user123/dfs/data/current/BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir2/blk_1073742516 for deletion
2016-11-26 11:13:22,569 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Scheduling blk_1073742517_1698 file /tmp/hadoop-user123/dfs/data/current/BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir2/blk_1073742517 for deletion
2016-11-26 11:13:22,569 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Scheduling blk_1073742518_1699 file /tmp/hadoop-user123/dfs/data/current/BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir2/blk_1073742518 for deletion
2016-11-26 11:13:22,569 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Scheduling blk_1073742519_1700 file /tmp/hadoop-user123/dfs/data/current/BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir2/blk_1073742519 for deletion
2016-11-26 11:13:22,569 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Scheduling blk_1073742520_1701 file /tmp/hadoop-user123/dfs/data/current/BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir2/blk_1073742520 for deletion
2016-11-26 11:13:22,569 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Scheduling blk_1073742521_1702 file /tmp/hadoop-user123/dfs/data/current/BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir2/blk_1073742521 for deletion
2016-11-26 11:13:22,571 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Deleted BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866 blk_1073742514_1695 file /tmp/hadoop-user123/dfs/data/current/BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir2/blk_1073742514
2016-11-26 11:13:22,571 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Deleted BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866 blk_1073742515_1696 file /tmp/hadoop-user123/dfs/data/current/BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir2/blk_1073742515
2016-11-26 11:13:22,576 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Deleted BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866 blk_1073742516_1697 file /tmp/hadoop-user123/dfs/data/current/BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir2/blk_1073742516
2016-11-26 11:13:22,576 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Deleted BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866 blk_1073742517_1698 file /tmp/hadoop-user123/dfs/data/current/BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir2/blk_1073742517
2016-11-26 11:13:22,577 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Deleted BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866 blk_1073742518_1699 file /tmp/hadoop-user123/dfs/data/current/BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir2/blk_1073742518
2016-11-26 11:13:22,577 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Deleted BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866 blk_1073742519_1700 file /tmp/hadoop-user123/dfs/data/current/BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir2/blk_1073742519
2016-11-26 11:13:22,577 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Deleted BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866 blk_1073742520_1701 file /tmp/hadoop-user123/dfs/data/current/BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir2/blk_1073742520
2016-11-26 11:13:22,577 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Deleted BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866 blk_1073742521_1702 file /tmp/hadoop-user123/dfs/data/current/BP-1195836218-175.45.20.822-1479972457866/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir2/blk_1073742521
2016-11-26 11:13:24,722 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
2016-11-26 11:13:24,727 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at namenode/175.45.20.822
************************************************************/<br>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I starting all daemons in the namenode and entered below command and its working fine.

hadoop dfsadmin -refreshNodes

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just restarted that namenode. It worked out for me.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that your Linux os has sent a request for an orderly shutdown of process.Please try restarting all nodes and give it a retry.